# Using jQuery Star Rating Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a question about [jQuery Star Rating Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing). I'm using this plugin to rate articles by people who bought them, but the articles can only be rated once. After rating an article, it must become read only (disabled) and I don't want to enable clicking it again or hovering it. I'm using the hover options and I want the text of the hover of the rated article to be fixed to the text when hovering this option (for example: "OK"). I need to know how I disable the radio buttons (make them read only), disable the hover methods and set the text to the hover text when clicking a radio button (function callback).

I tried setting the radio buttons to `disabled= true;` with JavaScript but it doesn't work.

Comment: What I need is to disable all the functions after a callback occurs: functions callback, focus and blur. After a callback occurs, nothing should happen when the user hovers or clicks again.

Comment: I think I succeeded in setting the text to the hover text. I just need to find out how to disable the radio buttons and hover functions.

Comment: I tried to replace the enabled radio buttons with read only buttons, but also then I can't set "checked= true;" on runtime.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at: http://rateit.codeplex.com, another rating plugin, which supports these scenarios. Look at the examples: http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm to find under sample 11 your request.